# php echo will not show variables correctly

Tags: php

I'm trying to get an output I need on some pages on my website.

On meta.php I have:

```
<?php $title1 = "this is the title for this $address"; ?>
```

On index.php I have:

```
<?PHP include('meta.php'); ?>

<?php $address = "address one"; ?>
```

and in `<head>` section:

```
<?php echo $title1; ?>
```

The problem is the output does not show the `$address`

What am I missing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first line substitutes `$address` as is at the moment of execution. It will become a string. So you need to set your variable BEFORE including it in the `$title`.

If you assign `$address` first, and then include, it will work.

```
<?php $address = "address one"; ?>
<?PHP include('meta.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Funny how sometimes the answer is right under your nose. Before asking here I tried reading in php.net and searching on Google for over an hour. Thanks for the heads up @Nanne :)

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of your code is wrong.

```
<?PHP include('meta.php'); ?>

<?php $address = "address one"; ?>
```

Translates to

```
<?php $title1 = "this is the title for this $address"; ?>

<?php $address = "address one"; ?>
```

PHP code is executed from top to bottom; so when `$title1` is set `$address` doesn't exists yet, so it can't replace it with the value you want.